# Using PLINK.EXE can I create multiple / different Output files automatically?

Tags: plink

I am trying to build automatic capture of Cisco ASA FW using the following....

```
for /f %%i in (firewalls.txt) do plink frank_belzer@%%i -pw scaFb673149! -m SCAConfigCapture.txt > testoutput.txt
```

This work great but I am wondering how to automatically create a different Output File for each device listed in firewalls.txt.

In the above example it overwrites the file each time the command loops to another device. If I use `>>` then the Output appends to the same file each loop.

Is there a way to create a different file each loop and have it rename itself appropriately.?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to create a different file each loop?

How about:

```
for /f %%i in (firewalls.txt) do (
  plink frank_belzer@%%i -pw scaFb673149! -m SCAConfigCapture.txt > %%ioutput.txt
)
```